# Resolving A Django Error on Form: Object has no attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Hi I'm trying to create a form that will when used update one model (Command_Node), and at the same time create an instance of another model (EC_NODE) that has a many to one relationship with the Command_Nodes.

However when I go onto the update view and submit the form I'm getting the following error any ideas on how I can resolve this error?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

```
AttributeError at /website/update/1
'Beacon' object has no attribute 'EC_Node_set'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/website/update/1
Django Version: 4.0.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Beacon' object has no attribute 'EC_Node_set'
```

This on traceback points to

```
       command_form.EC_Node_set.all()  # <- not sure with all _ and Maj here
```

Which I can understand. I think my intention here should be clear enough. I want to set an instance of EC_Node to hold the command just put in via the form, and I understand the error. I just don't know how to get around it so that the view/form does what I want.

**Relevant views.py**

```
def update(request, host_id):
    host_id = Command_Node.objects.get(pk=host_id)
    form = Command_Form(request.POST or None, instance=host_id)
    if form.is_valid():
        
        # Original suggestion was command_form = Command_Form.objects.first()
        command_form = form.cleaned_data['host_id']
        command_form.EC_Node_set.all()  # <- not sure with all _ and Maj here
        
        form.save()
        return redirect('home')
    return render (request, 'update.html', {'host_id':host_id,'form':form})
```

**Relevant models.py**

```
class Command_Node(models.Model):
    host_id = models.ForeignKey(Beacon, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    current_commands = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES, max_length=50, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.host_id)

class EC_Node(models.Model):
    Command_node = models.ForeignKey(Command_Node, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    command = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES, max_length=50, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Command_node)
```

**Relevant forms.py**

```
class Command_Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Command_Node
        fields = ('host_id','current_commands')

        host_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            required=True,
            queryset=Beacon.objects.all(),
            widget=forms.SelectMultiple(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                },
            )
        )

        current_comamnds = forms.ChoiceField(
            required=True,
            choices=CHOICES
        )

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        EC_Node.objects.create(
        command=self.cleaned_data["current_commands"],
        Command_node=self.instance
        )
        return super().save(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue now with the following:

```
 EC_Node.objects.create(Command_node=host_id, command=form.cleaned_data['current_commands'])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).